# Raspberry Pi Zero power with PS4 Controller cable

Tags: pi-zero

As the title says,

Is it possible to power a Raspberry Pi Zero with a PS4 controller micro usb cable?

I will be using a wifi usb adaptor and a 8gb micro sd card to build up a web server with appache2.

Comment: Pretty sure that's a regular microUSB cable and should be safe to try.

Comment: I will try it and feedback ;) Atleast the Zero is only 5$. Tkx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/2yekqj/can_the_ps4_controller_be_charged_with_any_micro/) the PS4 controller cable seems to be a completely normal micro USB cable and as such you should be able to use it with the Pi (even if it's not normal it's quite improbable that the the Pi will be damaged when using it).

I don't know if your question includes an appropriate charger, but the Pi Zero isn't consuming much power (at most 140mA according to [this](http://raspi.tv/2015/raspberry-pi-zero-power-measurements) site), so probably most chargers you find will do. AFAIK many give 0.5A or more, but that might not even be necessary if you aren't using accessories like wlan.

Comment: Note that "at most 140 mA" is a bit subjective as it notes there's a "USB keyboard/mouse dongle attached" but YMMV with such accessories and, e.g., a wifi adapter will probably double the figure.  When I've checked the Zero can use about that with nothing attached.   But finding a charger that puts out 300+ mA should not be very hard either, and a normal USB port in any computer *should* do as well.

Comment: As for something being a "PS4 Controller cable" that is probably a bit of branding to make a punter pay £15 for something retail that they could pick up for £1.50+V.A.T. from CPC {e.g. Part number ___CS17936___} (ironically, they are a division of Farnell, who are one of the pair of Official Distributors for the RPi)...! 8-P